# how can i find training error or error(D) and test error or error(s)

Tags: java, machine-learning, classification, weka, j48

I need to find training error or error(D) and test error or error(s).

hypothetically, to find error(s) we use formula : misclassified instances/total instances 
then to find error(D) we use 
error(s)+-confidenceInterval (sqrt(error(s(1-error(s)/n))))
here n= total instances

now how can i find misclassified instances? is it same as  Incorrectly Classified Instances which can be found using evaluate model of Evaluation class from weka?   let me know please

code:

```
import weka.classifiers.evaluation.Evaluation;
import weka.classifiers.trees.J48;
import weka.classifiers.trees.j48.ClassifierTree;
import weka.core.Instances;
import weka.core.converters.ConverterUtils.DataSource;
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public class J48Tree {
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {       
    //load dataset
     DataSource trainsource = new DataSource(".//training data.arff");
     DataSource testsource = new DataSource(".//test data.arff");
     Instances dataset=trainsource.getDataSet();
     Instances datatestset=testsource.getDataSet();     
     //set class index to the last attribute
     dataset.setClassIndex(dataset.numAttributes()-1);
     datatestset.setClassIndex(dataset.numAttributes()-1);          
     //create classifier
     J48 tree = new J48();
     //using an unpruned J48 
     tree.setUnpruned(true);
     //build the classifier
     tree.buildClassifier(dataset);     
     // evaluate classifier and print some statistics
     Evaluation eval = new Evaluation(dataset);
     eval.evaluateModel(tree, datatestset);
     System.out.println(eval.toSummaryString("\nResults\n======\n", true));         
 }    }
```

output:

Results

```
Correctly Classified Instances         540               22.2772 %
Incorrectly Classified Instances      1884               77.7228 %
Kappa statistic                          0.0644
K&B Relative Info Score              78375.7967 %
K&B Information Score                 1912.8906 bits      0.7891     bits/instance
Class complexity | order 0            7268.6047 bits      2.9986 bits/instance
Class complexity | scheme           725668.4216 bits    299.3682 bits/instance 
Complexity improvement     (Sf)    -718399.8169 bits   -296.3696 bits/instance
Mean absolute error                      0.2186
Root mean squared error                  0.3897
Relative absolute error                 91.6895 %
Root relative squared error            109.0212 %
Total Number of Instances             2424
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have doubt that "Incorrectly classified" and "misclassified" are the same, then **use the source**.

Looking at the Weka ssource code (and fortunately it is open source) is the *only* approach to learn what it is *exactly* doing. Even if I would tell you "yes it is", this may be correct for one version and wrong in another. So, use the source of your version as authorative resource.